# Suddenly, I Can't login with correct password (greeter & tty)

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, root, authentication, unity

This might be a duplicate of other password related questions but it's somehow eccentric.

I have 3 accounts in my **Ubuntu 12.10** system (one standard and two administrators). One of the administrator accounts is my main development account and suddenly before yesterday, it started to act weird (since the latest updates - Kernel and others:

- At the **greeter stage**, when I enter my password, it instantly returns 'Incorrect password'. It does not even check. (N.B: The password is absolutely correct)
- At **TTY**, impossible to login, once I enter my login name and then the password, it instantly re-prompts me to enter the login name...It feels like tha path to authenticate this account has been accidently locked or access-sealed.

I logged in with my second admin account and changed the password for the troublesome account, but no luck, reverted the password back to its original value and set the account to auto-login. rebooted and then, indeed the account logged in. Yet, the abonormality remains:

- I **cannot perform root privilege actions (sudo & gksudo)**. Once I enter my password, nothing happens. The only time when the password is accepted is when the screen is locked and that I am prompted to enter the password to unlock it.

I checked the ownership of my home folder and it's ok. Some help is very appreciated.

So to summarize:
- Can't login through lightdm
- sudo, gksudo & pkexec do not succeed
- su command fails
- if I provide the sudo command with an incorrect password, it checks and it return "Password incorrect", but if I provide the correct password, it does return nothing.
- The password keyring is accepted when I autologin.
- The password is accepted when I unlock the screen.

- I already changed the password and checked if my username belongs to groups like (sudo, admin, adm,....).

---

*Ubuntu 12.10
Unity
uname: Linux l502x 3.5.0-23-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 24 13:15:40 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux*

-------Some logs-----------
**

> cat /var/log/auth.log | grep hanine

**

```
Feb 12 03:21:05 l502x lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "hanine"
Feb 12 03:21:05 l502x lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:auth): auth could not identify password for [hanine]
Feb 12 03:21:05 l502x lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "hanine"
Feb 12 03:21:06 l502x lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "hanine"
Feb 12 03:21:38 l502x lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "hanine"
Feb 12 03:21:43 l502x lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "hanine"
Feb 12 03:23:36 l502x sudo:    admin : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/hanine ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/passwd hanine
Feb 12 03:23:36 l502x passwd[5502]: pam_smbpass(passwd:chauthtok): Failed to find entry for user hanine.
Feb 12 03:23:52 l502x passwd[5502]: pam_unix(passwd:chauthtok): password changed for hanine
Feb 12 03:23:52 l502x passwd[5502]: pam_smbpass(passwd:chauthtok): Failed to find entry for user hanine.
Feb 12 03:24:17 l502x sudo:    admin : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/hanine ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/passwd hanine
Feb 12 03:24:17 l502x passwd[5520]: pam_smbpass(passwd:chauthtok): Failed to find entry for user hanine.
Feb 12 03:24:24 l502x passwd[5520]: pam_unix(passwd:chauthtok): password changed for hanine
Feb 12 03:24:24 l502x passwd[5520]: pam_smbpass(passwd:chauthtok): Failed to find entry for user hanine.
Feb 12 03:27:51 l502x sudo:    admin : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/hanine ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/rm .xsession-errors
Feb 12 03:28:42 l502x sudo:    admin : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/hanine ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/rm .Xauthority
Feb 12 03:29:22 l502x sudo:    admin : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/hanine ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/mkdir .xsession-errors-old-files
Feb 12 03:29:36 l502x sudo:    admin : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/hanine ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/mv .xsession-errors.old .xsession-errors_OLD1 .xsession-errors-old-files .xsession-errors-old-files/
Feb 12 03:34:15 l502x sudo:    admin : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/hanine ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/sakis3g connect
Feb 12 14:10:08 l502x lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "hanine"
Feb 12 14:10:15 l502x lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "hanine"
Feb 12 14:13:23 l502x accounts-daemon: request by system-bus-name::1.66 [gnome-control-center user-accounts pid:3028 uid:1001]: enable automatic login for user 'hanine' (1000)
Feb 12 14:16:54 l502x lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "hanine"
Feb 12 14:16:54 l502x lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:auth): auth could not identify password for [hanine]
Feb 12 14:16:55 l502x lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "hanine"
Feb 12 14:16:55 l502x lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "hanine"
Feb 12 14:16:57 l502x lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=:1 ruser= rhost=  user=hanine
Feb 12 14:16:59 l502x lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "hanine"
Feb 12 14:17:43 l502x lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "hanine"
Feb 12 14:18:00 l502x lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=:0 ruser= rhost=  user=hanine
Feb 12 14:18:02 l502x lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "hanine"
Feb 12 14:18:06 l502x lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "hanine"
Feb 12 14:18:14 l502x lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "hanine"
Feb 12 14:18:17 l502x lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "hanine"
Feb 12 14:19:05 l502x lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm-autologin:session): session opened for user hanine by (uid=0)
Feb 12 14:20:04 l502x gnome-keyring-daemon[2173]: keyring alias directory: /home/hanine/.local/share/keyrings
Feb 12 14:50:18 l502x gnome-screensaver-dialog: pam_unix(gnome-screensaver:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=1000 euid=1000 tty=:0.0 ruser= rhost=  user=hanine
Feb 12 14:55:48 l502x sudo:    admin : TTY=pts/3 ; PWD=/home/admin ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/chown hanine:hanine /home/hanine/
Feb 12 14:59:22 l502x polkitd(authority=local): Operator of unix-session:/org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Session1 successfully authenticated as unix-user:admin to gain TEMPORARY authorization for action com.ubuntu-tweak.daemon.clean for system-bus-name::1.138 [/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/ubuntu-tweak] (owned by unix-user:hanine)
Feb 12 15:56:26 l502x polkitd(authority=local): Operator of unix-session:/org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Session1 FAILED to authenticate to gain authorization for action org.gnome.controlcenter.user-accounts.administration for unix-process:10018:582882 [gnome-control-center user-accounts] (owned by unix-user:hanine)
Feb 12 16:16:41 l502x sudo:    admin : TTY=tty2 ; PWD=/home/admin ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/adduser hanine sudo
Feb 12 16:16:49 l502x sudo:    admin : TTY=tty2 ; PWD=/home/admin ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/adduser hanine admin
Feb 12 16:16:49 l502x gpasswd[17020]: user hanine added by root to group admin
Feb 12 17:11:49 l502x lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm-autologin:session): session closed for user hanine
Feb 12 17:11:49 l502x lightdm: pam_xdg_support(lightdm-autologin:session): Could not delete directory /run/user/hanine
Feb 12 17:23:58 l502x lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "hanine"
Feb 12 17:23:58 l502x lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:auth): auth could not identify password for [hanine]
Feb 12 17:23:58 l502x lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "hanine"
Feb 12 17:23:59 l502x lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "hanine"
Feb 12 17:24:04 l502x lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "hanine"
Feb 12 17:24:08 l502x lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=:0 ruser= rhost=  user=hanine
Feb 12 17:24:10 l502x lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "hanine"
Feb 12 17:25:36 l502x lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm-autologin:session): session opened for user hanine by (uid=0)
Feb 12 17:26:29 l502x gnome-keyring-daemon[2147]: keyring alias directory: /home/hanine/.local/share/keyrings
Feb 12 17:42:29 l502x sudo:    admin : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/admin ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/chown -R hanine:hanine /home/hanine
Feb 12 17:47:36 l502x gnome-screensaver-dialog: pam_unix(gnome-screensaver:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=1000 euid=1000 tty=:0.0 ruser= rhost=  user=hanine
Feb 12 17:56:14 l502x su[17624]: pam_unix(su:auth): authentication failure; logname=hanine uid=1000 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/4 ruser=hanine rhost=  user=root
Feb 12 17:56:16 l502x su[17624]: FAILED su for root by hanine
Feb 12 17:56:16 l502x su[17624]: - /dev/pts/4 hanine:root
Feb 12 17:56:57 l502x su[17888]: pam_unix(su:auth): authentication failure; logname=hanine uid=1000 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/4 ruser=hanine rhost=  user=root
Feb 12 17:56:59 l502x su[17888]: FAILED su for root by hanine
Feb 12 17:56:59 l502x su[17888]: - /dev/pts/4 hanine:root
Feb 12 17:59:07 l502x polkitd(authority=local): Operator of unix-session:/org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Session1 FAILED to authenticate to gain authorization for action org.freedesktop.policykit.exec for unix-process:16882:180734 [bash] (owned by unix-user:hanine)
Feb 12 17:59:07 l502x pkexec[18604]: hanine: Error executing command as another user: Request dismissed [USER=root] [TTY=/dev/pts/4] [CWD=/home/hanine] [COMMAND=/usr/bin/gedit]
Feb 12 18:17:33 l502x lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm-autologin:session): session closed for user hanine
Feb 12 18:17:33 l502x lightdm: pam_xdg_support(lightdm-autologin:session): Could not delete directory /run/user/hanine
Feb 12 18:32:48 l502x lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm-autologin:session): session opened for user hanine by (uid=0)
Feb 12 18:33:39 l502x gnome-keyring-daemon[2142]: keyring alias directory: /home/hanine/.local/share/keyrings
Feb 12 19:05:48 l502x lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "hanine"
Feb 12 19:07:38 l502x sudo:    admin : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/admin ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/passwd hanine
Feb 12 19:07:38 l502x passwd[17421]: pam_smbpass(passwd:chauthtok): Failed to find entry for user hanine.
Feb 12 19:07:44 l502x passwd[17421]: pam_unix(passwd:chauthtok): password changed for hanine
Feb 12 19:07:44 l502x passwd[17421]: pam_smbpass(passwd:chauthtok): Failed to find entry for user hanine.
Feb 12 19:08:03 l502x lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "hanine"
Feb 12 19:08:13 l502x lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=:1 ruser= rhost=  user=hanine
Feb 12 19:08:15 l502x lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "hanine"
Feb 12 19:08:18 l502x lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=:1 ruser= rhost=  user=hanine
Feb 12 19:08:20 l502x lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "hanine"
Feb 12 19:09:47 l502x lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm-autologin:session): session opened for user hanine by (uid=0)
Feb 12 19:10:39 l502x gnome-keyring-daemon[2099]: keyring alias directory: /home/hanine/.local/share/keyrings
Feb 12 19:11:27 l502x sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): authentication failure; logname=hanine uid=1000 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/0 ruser=hanine rhost=  user=hanine
Feb 12 19:12:31 l502x sudo:    admin : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/admin ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/passwd hanine
Feb 12 19:12:31 l502x passwd[4491]: pam_smbpass(passwd:chauthtok): Failed to find entry for user hanine.
Feb 12 19:12:38 l502x passwd[4491]: pam_unix(passwd:chauthtok): password changed for hanine
Feb 12 19:12:38 l502x passwd[4491]: pam_smbpass(passwd:chauthtok): Failed to find entry for user hanine.
Feb 12 22:44:16 l502x sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): authentication failure; logname=hanine uid=1000 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/0 ruser=hanine rhost=  user=hanine
Feb 13 13:24:01 l502x lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm-autologin:session): session opened for user hanine by (uid=0)
Feb 13 13:24:52 l502x gnome-keyring-daemon[2061]: keyring alias directory: /home/hanine/.local/share/keyrings
Feb 13 13:40:49 l502x polkitd(authority=local): Operator of unix-session:/org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Session1 FAILED to authenticate to gain authorization for action org.freedesktop.policykit.exec for unix-process:3554:15127 [bash] (owned by unix-user:hanine)
Feb 13 13:40:49 l502x pkexec[8783]: hanine: Error executing command as another user: Request dismissed [USER=root] [TTY=/dev/pts/0] [CWD=/home/hanine] [COMMAND=/usr/bin/apt-get update]
Feb 13 13:49:13 l502x polkitd(authority=local): Operator of unix-session:/org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Session1 FAILED to authenticate to gain authorization for action org.freedesktop.policykit.exec for unix-process:10395:133011 [bash] (owned by unix-user:hanine)
Feb 13 13:49:13 l502x pkexec[11324]: hanine: Error executing command as another user: Request dismissed [USER=root] [TTY=/dev/pts/2] [CWD=/home/hanine] [COMMAND=/usr/bin/gedit]
```

**Summary of other logs** (the one that got modified right after an unsuccessfull login):

**-----OUTPUT in auth.log between 14:52 & 14:53---**

```
Feb 13 14:52:37 l502x lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm-greeter:session): session opened for user lightdm by (uid=0)
Feb 13 14:52:37 l502x lightdm: pam_ck_connector(lightdm-greeter:session): nox11 mode, ignoring PAM_TTY :2
Feb 13 14:52:37 l502x dbus[959]: [system] Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.50" (uid=1000 pid=2758 comm="/usr/lib/indicator-session/indicator-session-servi") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.14" (uid=0 pid=1528 comm="/usr/sbin/console-kit-daemon --no-daemon ")
Feb 13 14:52:37 l502x dbus[959]: [system] Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.114" (uid=1001 pid=17063 comm="/usr/lib/indicator-session/indicator-session-servi") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.14" (uid=0 pid=1528 comm="/usr/sbin/console-kit-daemon --no-daemon ")
Feb 13 14:52:38 l502x lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "admin"
Feb 13 14:52:38 l502x lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "admin"
Feb 13 14:52:38 l502x dbus[959]: [system] Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.165" (uid=110 pid=5906 comm="/usr/lib/indicator-session/indicator-session-servi") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.14" (uid=0 pid=1528 comm="/usr/sbin/console-kit-daemon --no-daemon ")
Feb 13 14:52:39  dbus[959]: last message repeated 9 times
Feb 13 14:52:39 l502x dbus[959]: [system] Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.170" (uid=110 pid=5908 comm="/usr/lib/indicator-datetime/indicator-datetime-ser") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.14" (uid=0 pid=1528 comm="/usr/sbin/console-kit-daemon --no-daemon ")
Feb 13 14:52:40 l502x lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "hanine"
Feb 13 14:53:05  lightdm: last message repeated 2 times
```

**-------OUTPUT in syslog between 14:52 & 14:53-----**-

```
Feb 13 14:39:01 l502x CRON[32704]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -ignore_readdir_race -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete)
Feb 13 14:52:34 l502x acpid: client 1468[0:0] has disconnected
Feb 13 14:52:34 l502x acpid: client connected from 16547[0:0]
Feb 13 14:52:34 l502x acpid: 1 client rule loaded
Feb 13 14:52:36 l502x acpid: client connected from 5795[0:0]
Feb 13 14:52:36 l502x acpid: 1 client rule loaded
Feb 13 14:52:38 l502x rtkit-daemon[2221]: Successfully made thread 5947 of process 5947 (n/a) owned by '110' high priority at nice level -11.
Feb 13 14:52:38 l502x rtkit-daemon[2221]: Supervising 7 threads of 3 processes of 3 users.
Feb 13 14:52:39 l502x goa[5965]: goa-daemon version 3.6.0 starting [main.c:112, main()]
Feb 13 14:52:39 l502x rtkit-daemon[2221]: Successfully made thread 5977 of process 5947 (n/a) owned by '110' RT at priority 5.
Feb 13 14:52:39 l502x rtkit-daemon[2221]: Supervising 8 threads of 3 processes of 3 users.
Feb 13 14:52:39 l502x rtkit-daemon[2221]: Successfully made thread 5979 of process 5947 (n/a) owned by '110' RT at priority 5.
Feb 13 14:52:39 l502x rtkit-daemon[2221]: Supervising 9 threads of 3 processes of 3 users.
Feb 13 14:52:39 l502x rtkit-daemon[2221]: Successfully made thread 5985 of process 5985 (n/a) owned by '110' high priority at nice level -11.
Feb 13 14:52:39 l502x rtkit-daemon[2221]: Supervising 10 threads of 4 processes of 3 users.
Feb 13 14:52:39 l502x pulseaudio[5985]: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
Feb 13 14:53:11 l502x acpid: client 16547[0:0] has disconnected
Feb 13 14:53:11 l502x acpid: client 5795[0:0] has disconnected
Feb 13 14:53:11 l502x acpid: client connected from 16547[0:0]
Feb 13 14:53:11 l502x acpid: 1 client rule loaded
```

**----------------OUTPUT in Xorg.0.log between 14:52 & 14:53---------------**
...

```
[  5193.182] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-2A7E24AED066D4B3B8BAB98261965C829292FC7F.xkm
[  5195.444] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-2A7E24AED066D4B3B8BAB98261965C829292FC7F.xkm
[  5200.561] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-2A7E24AED066D4B3B8BAB98261965C829292FC7F.xkm
[  5202.771] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-2A7E24AED066D4B3B8BAB98261965C829292FC7F.xkm
[  5244.342] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-2A7E24AED066D4B3B8BAB98261965C829292FC7F.xkm
[  5244.724] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-2A7E24AED066D4B3B8BAB98261965C829292FC7F.xkm
[  5296.302] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-2A7E24AED066D4B3B8BAB98261965C829292FC7F.xkm
[  5298.589] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-2A7E24AED066D4B3B8BAB98261965C829292FC7F.xkm
[  5336.975] (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
```

**----------------OUTPUT in Xorg.1.log between 14:52 & 14:53---------------**

```
[  2466.917] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2.2/2-1.2.2:1.0/input/input16/event14"
[  2466.917] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "DELL DELL USB Laser Mouse" (type: MOUSE, id 12)
[  2466.918] (II) evdev: DELL DELL USB Laser Mouse: initialized for relative axes.
[  2466.918] (**) DELL DELL USB Laser Mouse: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[  2466.918] (**) DELL DELL USB Laser Mouse: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[  2466.918] (**) DELL DELL USB Laser Mouse: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[  2466.918] (**) DELL DELL USB Laser Mouse: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[  5336.975] (II) Open ACPI successful (/var/run/acpid.socket)
[  5336.975] (II) AIGLX: Resuming AIGLX clients after VT switch
[  5336.996] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "AUO", prod id 8940
[  5336.996] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[  5336.996] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   65.10  1366 1382 1390 1398  768 771 775 776 +hsync -vsync (46.6 kHz eP)
[  5337.061] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: touchpad found
[  5339.035] (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
[  5373.403] (II) Open ACPI successful (/var/run/acpid.socket)
[  5373.403] (II) AIGLX: Resuming AIGLX clients after VT switch
[  5373.416] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "AUO", prod id 8940
[  5373.416] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[  5373.416] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   65.10  1366 1382 1390 1398  768 771 775 776 +hsync -vsync (46.6 kHz eP)
[  5373.481] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: touchpad found
[  5408.188] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "AUO", prod id 8940
[  5408.188] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[  5408.188] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   65.10  1366 1382 1390 1398  768 771 775 776 +hsync -vsync (46.6 kHz eP)
[  5412.873] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "AUO", prod id 8940
[  5412.873] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[  5412.873] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   65.10  1366 1382 1390 1398  768 771 775 776 +hsync -vsync (46.6 kHz eP)
```

**----------------OUTPUT in Xorg.3.log between 14:52 & 14:53---------------**

```
[  5339.350] (**) evdev: Dell WMI hotkeys: Device: "/dev/input/event5"
[  5339.350] (--) evdev: Dell WMI hotkeys: Vendor 0 Product 0
[  5339.350] (--) evdev: Dell WMI hotkeys: Found keys
[  5339.350] (II) evdev: Dell WMI hotkeys: Configuring as keyboard
[  5339.350] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/virtual/input/input5/event5"
[  5339.350] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Dell WMI hotkeys" (type: KEYBOARD, id 15)
[  5339.350] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[  5339.350] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[  5339.350] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "fr"
[  5373.402] (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
[  5373.543] (II) evdev: Dell WMI hotkeys: Close
[  5373.543] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[  5373.543] (II) UnloadModule: "synaptics"
[  5373.543] (II) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Close
[  5373.543] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[  5373.543] (II) evdev: DELL DELL USB Laser Mouse: Close
[  5373.543] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[  5373.543] (II) evdev: Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_2HDM: Close
[  5373.543] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[  5373.543] (II) evdev: Sleep Button: Close
[  5373.543] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[  5373.543] (II) evdev: Power Button: Close
[  5373.543] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[  5373.543] (II) evdev: Video Bus: Close
[  5373.543] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[  5373.543] (II) evdev: Video Bus: Close
[  5373.543] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[  5373.543] (II) evdev: Power Button: Close
[  5373.544] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[  5373.555] Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

**----------------OUTPUT in lightdm.log between 14:52 & 14:53---------------**

```
[+5322.11s] DEBUG: Session 5897 failed during authentication
[+5322.12s] DEBUG: Session 5899 got 1 message(s) from PAM
[+5322.12s] DEBUG: Prompt greeter with 1 message(s)
[+5324.52s] DEBUG: Greeter start authentication for hanine
[+5324.52s] DEBUG: Session 5899: Sending SIGTERM
[+5324.52s] DEBUG: Started session 6005 with service 'lightdm', username 'hanine'
[+5324.52s] DEBUG: Session 5899 terminated with signal 15
[+5324.52s] DEBUG: Session 5899 failed during authentication
[+5324.53s] DEBUG: Session 6005 got 1 message(s) from PAM
[+5324.53s] DEBUG: Prompt greeter with 1 message(s)
[+5332.64s] DEBUG: Continue authentication
[+5332.67s] DEBUG: Session 6005 exited with return value 1
[+5332.67s] DEBUG: Session 6005 failed during authentication
[+5332.67s] DEBUG: Authenticate result for user hanine: Authentication stopped before completion
[+5332.67s] DEBUG: Greeter start authentication for hanine
[+5332.68s] DEBUG: Started session 6050 with service 'lightdm', username 'hanine'
[+5332.69s] DEBUG: Session 6050 got 1 message(s) from PAM
[+5332.69s] DEBUG: Prompt greeter with 1 message(s)
[+5339.70s] DEBUG: Continue authentication
[+5339.73s] DEBUG: Session 6050 exited with return value 1
[+5339.73s] DEBUG: Session 6050 failed during authentication
[+5339.73s] DEBUG: Authenticate result for user hanine: Authentication stopped before completion
[+5339.73s] DEBUG: Greeter start authentication for hanine
[+5339.73s] DEBUG: Started session 6083 with service 'lightdm', username 'hanine'
[+5339.75s] DEBUG: Session 6083 got 1 message(s) from PAM
[+5339.75s] DEBUG: Prompt greeter with 1 message(s)
[+5349.52s] DEBUG: Greeter start authentication for admin
[+5349.52s] DEBUG: Session 6083: Sending SIGTERM
[+5349.53s] DEBUG: Started session 6135 with service 'lightdm', username 'admin'
[+5349.53s] DEBUG: Session 6083 terminated with signal 15
[+5349.53s] DEBUG: Session 6083 failed during authentication
[+5349.54s] DEBUG: Session 6135 got 1 message(s) from PAM
[+5349.54s] DEBUG: Prompt greeter with 1 message(s)
[+5353.99s] DEBUG: Continue authentication
[+5354.00s] DEBUG: Session 6135 got 1 message(s) from PAM
[+5354.00s] DEBUG: Prompt greeter with 1 message(s)
[+5354.03s] DEBUG: Session 6135 authentication complete with return value 0: Success
[+5354.03s] DEBUG: Authenticate result for user admin: Success
[+5354.05s] DEBUG: User admin authorized
[+5354.06s] DEBUG: Greeter requests session ubuntu
[+5354.06s] DEBUG: Using session ubuntu
[+5354.06s] DEBUG: Switching to existing session for user admin
[+5354.06s] DEBUG: Unlocking display
[+5354.06s] DEBUG: Unlocking ConsoleKit session 771ea75a3c00ed10682632e750620a0b-1360763926.621199-1814231122
[+5354.07s] DEBUG: Activating VT 8
[+5354.65s] DEBUG: Stopping greeter display being switched from
[+5354.65s] DEBUG: Stopping display
[+5354.65s] DEBUG: Session 5800: Sending SIGTERM
[+5354.78s] DEBUG: Greeter closed communication channel
[+5354.78s] DEBUG: Session 5800 exited with return value 0
[+5354.78s] DEBUG: Greeter quit
[+5354.78s] DEBUG: Sending signal 15 to process 5795
[+5354.81s] DEBUG: Process 5795 exited with return value 0
[+5354.81s] DEBUG: X server stopped
[+5354.81s] DEBUG: Removing X server authority /var/run/lightdm/root/:2
[+5354.81s] DEBUG: Releasing VT 9
[+5354.81s] DEBUG: Display server stopped
[+5354.81s] DEBUG: Display stopped
```

**-------OUTPUT in x-2-greeter.log between 14:52 & 14:53---------------**

```
[+11.54s] DEBUG: Authentication complete for user hanine with return code 19
[+11.54s] DEBUG: Starting authentication for user hanine...
[+11.54s] DEBUG: Wrote 22 bytes to daemon
[+11.55s] DEBUG: Read 8 bytes from daemon
[+11.55s] DEBUG: Read 36 bytes from daemon
[+11.55s] DEBUG: Prompt user with 1 message(s)
[+18.57s] DEBUG: Providing response to display manager
[+18.57s] DEBUG: Wrote 24 bytes to daemon
[+18.59s] DEBUG: Read 8 bytes from daemon
[+18.59s] DEBUG: Read 18 bytes from daemon
[+18.59s] DEBUG: Authentication complete for user hanine with return code 19
[+18.60s] DEBUG: Starting authentication for user hanine...
[+18.60s] DEBUG: Wrote 22 bytes to daemon
[+18.61s] DEBUG: Read 8 bytes from daemon
[+18.61s] DEBUG: Read 36 bytes from daemon
[+18.61s] DEBUG: Prompt user with 1 message(s)
[+28.39s] DEBUG: Starting authentication for user admin...
[+28.39s] DEBUG: Wrote 21 bytes to daemon
[+28.41s] DEBUG: Read 8 bytes from daemon
[+28.41s] DEBUG: Read 35 bytes from daemon
[+28.41s] DEBUG: Prompt user with 1 message(s)
[+28.74s] DEBUG: Setting keyboard layout to 'fr'
[+32.85s] DEBUG: Providing response to display manager
[+32.85s] DEBUG: Wrote 24 bytes to daemon
[+32.86s] DEBUG: Read 8 bytes from daemon
[+32.86s] DEBUG: Read 61 bytes from daemon
[+32.86s] DEBUG: Prompt user with 1 message(s)
[+32.92s] DEBUG: Read 8 bytes from daemon
[+32.92s] DEBUG: Read 17 bytes from daemon
[+32.92s] DEBUG: Authentication complete for user admin with return code 0
[+32.93s] DEBUG: Starting session ubuntu
[+32.93s] DEBUG: Wrote 18 bytes to daemon
[+33.51s] DEBUG: Read 8 bytes from daemon
[+33.51s] DEBUG: Read 4 bytes from daemon
** Message: PID 5902 (we are 5902) sent signal 15, shutting down...
```

(nm-applet:5902): libappindicator-WARNING **: Unable to send signal for NewStatus: The connection is closed

**in x-2 log, authentication return code for user hanine is 19 (failure) while admin has 0 (success).**

Comment: Any problem with the definitions in /etc/login.defs?

Comment: Does anything appear in the system logs? Particularly `/var/log/auth.log`, but look at all the files in `/var/log` that are modified at the time of your ubsuccessful attempts. Has a file in `/etc/pam.d` or `/etc/pam.conf` changed recently? Are the permissions of `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` ok? Copy-paste log lines and command output that you need help to interpret.

Comment: @mdpc I don't think so. The file seems okay. It is a common file for all accounts. And as I mentioned, I can login with the two other accounts.

Comment: @Gilles this is what I've been doing. Yet nothing weird. I am surprised it only affects one account. I am pasting right away some content from log files in my question. Maybe u could help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem solved.

Here are the actions I carried out before the problem got solved:

- **sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3** (in order to revert back to
  supported gnome packages like nautilus, ...etc)
- creating directory: /var/lib/samba and adding myself to samba passwords databse (**sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/samba &&
  sudo smbpasswd -a myusername**
- **sudo pam-auth-update** (all the authentication modules were already
  selected, so I just cliked okay).

Troubleshooting here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2115288

Answer (score 1):

I had done `chmod 555` to my home folder which created the problem. The solution is to change the permissions back by using someone else's laptop.

```
ssh (your laptop username)@(your IP)
cd ..
chmod 777 (your username on laptop)
```